# I am not able to send a txt file over ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "Documents");
    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdir();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, "file.txt");

    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.append("Test");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@hotmail.com");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of the mail");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."),12);
}
```

This is the code I am having trouble with. For some reason, whenever I click the button to run this function block and select an application to use it on, it says that the file type is not supported. I have external file access and I have tested if file exists after I write, there is nothing wrong with it there.

I also have this block on onCreate function of the activity:

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```

Without this block, the program crashes whenever I attempt to send an attachment and I wonder what is the cause.

I am using API 22.

**EDIT**

Implemented FileProvider but it still is not able to send the file to another applications.
This is how I send it:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.company.documentproject_1.fileprovider", file);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "emailaddress@hotmail.com");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of the mail");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.addFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."),12);
```

This is AndroidManifest provider.

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.company.documentproject_1.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

provider_paths in xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

This is the error I get when I boot up the application, please note that I removed StrictMode:

```
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for cn.teddymobile.free.anteater.den.provider
```

Comment: Posting the crash would be helpful to understand what is going on.

Comment: `if (!dir.mkdir()) {Toast( ... Sorry could not create dir ..); return;}`

Comment: `catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }` If you have this catch you still launch that intent. Instead you should display a toast to inform the user and return/stop.

Comment: Remove that strict mode stuff. A shame.

Comment: You are not showing how you instantiate the used `file` variable. Or is it still the same? Then you will have an exception if you try to get an uri.  Please do and tell the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()`. You posted new code and i should look. But why? Is there a problem? And what has that provider error to do with that code?

Comment: Everything else except for the intent block I added again is the same.  Absolute path of the file is `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/file.txt`. The problem still persists. I am unable to share the file to any other application, it says that file type is not supported.

Comment: Did you add the code i proposed? If the file is not created you would still launch the intent.

Comment: I wasn't expecting that, I added a toast on file write exception and it really can't write to that file. I also added a toast to mkdir() and it's alright.

Comment: I printed the exception and it is giving me `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/file.txt (Permission Denied)`

Comment: Thank you for your direction, I didn't know I had to manually ask permissions from the user from onCreate function. Problem is solved now thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Will produce a FileUriExposedException.

That will not work.

You have to use a file provider and obtain your uri with:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(......, file);
```

Comment: Hello, I made some changes to the original post, can you please help me out?